Substituting number of simulations (n) in rnorm() using a list of predetermined values
I'm using rnorm() but instead of substituting the number of simulations n with just one variable, I would like to do this multiple times with n having predetermined values from a series of values.  (In my project, I will need to do this 11,600+ times as there are 11,600+ predetermined values which I need to use rnorm() for - but the mean and standard deviation will be constant. To simplify everything for this discussion, I will just assume I have 10 predetermined values representing the number of simulations I would like to do.)
unit.cost <- rnorm(n=728, mean = 8403.86, sd = 1000)

Instead of just using "728" as the number of simulations (n), I would want to automatically substitute iteratively using these series of values: 728, 628, 100, 150, 99, 867, 934, 11, 67, 753. (I also want to use these series of values in the same order - and not just randomly using them, as the expected output should be a data frame listing the unit.cost using the predetermined values of n. Note that both mean and sd are constant.)
Upon search, it looks like for loop would be an ideal candidate to do this setup?

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This seems like an excellent use case for lapply().  If your vector of ns was called nstouse  then something like nsout <- lapply(nstouse, rnorm, mean = 8403.86, sd = 1000)

It may be difficult to expect a data frame to hold the results since the "n"s vary.

@Edward: I don't agree. See either PGSA's or Carls answer below.  Even without summarising to mean, the results could be returned as a list of lists (each with entries for n and a vector of values or as a data frame with columns for iteration, n, and value.

To get a data frame as the output, including the n parameter used, you could do the following:
library(tidyverse)

param_n <- c(728, 628, 100, 150, 99, 867, 934, 11, 67, 753)

set.seed(1)

cost_df <- map(param_n, \(param_n){
  tibble(
    param_n,
    unit_cost = rnorm(param_n, mean = 8403.86, sd = 1000)
    )
}) |> 
  bind_rows()

cost_df
#> # A tibble: 4,337 × 2
#>    param_n unit_cost
#>      <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1     728     7777.
#>  2     728     8588.
#>  3     728     7568.
#>  4     728     9999.
#>  5     728     8733.
#>  6     728     7583.
#>  7     728     8891.
#>  8     728     9142.
#>  9     728     8980.
#> 10     728     8098.
#> # ℹ 4,327 more rows

Created on 2024-04-22 with reprex v2.1.0

using lapply(), we apply the same function to each element of your vector, then return the results in a list (hence the l of lapply).
rnorm takes the arguments rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1) - we want your vector of values to fill the n argument, so we specify the mean and sd:
nstouse <- c(728, 628, 100, 150, 99, 867, 934, 11, 67, 753)

nsout <- lapply(nstouse, rnorm, mean = 8403.86, sd = 1000)

gives:
> str(nsout)
List of 10
 $ : num [1:728] 9168 8497 7782 6304 8711 ...
 $ : num [1:628] 7709 6477 9047 7756 9781 ...
 $ : num [1:100] 9761 7519 8675 8413 9376 ...
 $ : num [1:150] 8378 9830 6052 7293 9908 ...
 $ : num [1:99] 7074 8290 8287 10091 10256 ...
 $ : num [1:867] 8034 9261 9053 8760 10571 ...
 $ : num [1:934] 9351 8425 8199 7613 9412 ...
 $ : num [1:11] 8540 7392 8925 8540 8259 ...
 $ : num [1:67] 8366 7445 9361 9586 7632 ...
 $ : num [1:753] 8637 8854 8402 6992 8878 ...

further request for means.
I will present them in a data frame:
dfout <- data.frame(n = nstouse,
                    mean = sapply(nsout, mean))

gives
     n     mean
1  728 8362.516
2  628 8404.694
3  100 8536.995
4  150 8566.984
5   99 8428.155
6  867 8373.285
7  934 8388.744
8   11 8356.367
9   67 8612.405
10 753 8406.939


Thanks PGSA. Just a question, if I want to get the mean of the values per ROW, is there a way to do that returning a list of mean for every row? Thank you.

@ArvinHadlos yes that relatively straightforward - see the edit to my answer.  I've structured it as a data frame but hopefully it should be relatively clear how to have it as a list if required.
